# JNI RegisterNatives with native call in static initializer

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I've encountered an interesting problem when using the JNI. To give an example, I have a class like the following:

```
public class AClass {
    private static int someInteger;

    public static native int getInteger();

    static {
        someInteger = getInteger();
    }
}
```

The problem with the above class is that if I have a JNI library that tries to register natives with JNI_OnLoad, like the following:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
    JNIEnv *env; (*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    JNINativeMethod table[] = {
            {"getInteger", "()I", (void *) &native_getInteger)},
        };

    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "AClass");

    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env)) {
        (*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    printf("RegisterNatives return value: %d", (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls, table, 1));
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

The above code fails after `JNIEnv.FindClass` is called, because `FindClass` runs the static initializer block of the target class. In this case, the target class calls a native method that will only be linked after the `RegisterNatives` call. This results in an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Is there a way to call `JNIEnv.FindClass` without running the static initializer block of the target class in order to link native methods for that class? Ideally, I'd like to avoid changing java code, if possible.

Comment: Use a shared library, `System.loadLibrary()`, and the conventional naming for native methods as generated by `javah`, instead of `RegisterNatives()`.

Comment: Is there any way to do it with RegisterNatives or is it impossible in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to use RegisterNatives with classes which use native calls in  section.